# Django translating MySQL query to Django Query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

How can i get the equivalent of this MySQL script in Django views? The depart_city, arrive_city, and travel_date will be inputed by the user.

Here is my Models

```
class Driver(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)




class Schedule(models.Model):
depart_time = models.TimeField()
arrive_time = models.TimeField()



class TravelDate(models.Model):
start_date = models.DateField(null = True)
interval = models.IntegerField(null = True) 


class Route(models.Model): 
depart_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
arrive_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)
schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
traveldate = models.ForeignKey(TravelDate)
```

Here is my MySQL script. This works when i run it on MySQL workbench but I'm not sure how to translate this to Django Query

```
    SELECT busapp_route.depart_city, busapp_route.arrive_city, busapp_driver.first_name, busapp_schedule.depart_time 
FROM (((busapp_route INNER JOIN busapp_driver ON busapp_route.driver_id = busapp_driver.id) 
INNER JOIN busapp_schedule ON busapp_route.schedule_id = busapp_schedule.id)
INNER JOIN busapp_traveldate ON busapp_route.traveldate_id = busapp_traveldate.id) 
WHERE busapp_route.depart_city='Tropoje' AND busapp_route.arrive_city='Tirane'
AND (DATEDIFF('2017-11-26', busapp_traveldate.start_date) % busapp_traveldate.interval = 0);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just import data? Rebuild an app?
The Django ORM which is one of the strengths of Django will do a lot more.

Comment: I'm basically stuck on trying to do repeating events in Django. I'm building a website where the driver registers themselves  and specifies the route A --> B, depart time, arrive time, and how often they do this route (every day, every other day, every 3 days...). When a user searches for a bus from city A --> B on a specific date I wan't to display the buses that run on that day.

Comment: Just thought if I gt you right, you're building an app which keeps bus routes from one city to another? Or are you talking about some local public transport? In the latter case things might become quite easy as you would be able to simply define the weekdays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support MySQL DATEDIFF natively. As a workaround, you could use something like this:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

routes = Route.objects\
    .values('depart_city', 'arrive_city', 'driver__first_name', 'schedule__depart_time', 'traveldate__start_date')\
    .annotate(datediff_mod=RawSQL("DATEDIFF(%s, busapp_traveldate.start_date) MOD busapp_traveldate.interval", ('2017-11-26', )))\
    .filter(depart_city='Tropoje', arrive_city='Tirane', datediff_mod = 0)
```

I don't use MySQL so I couldn't test this, but I'm pretty sure it should work or maybe at least give you an idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's a good idea, trying to solve this from the SQL side.

And what you're building there, is not trivial as there are a lot of things to keep in mind.

Your current Model setup lags some points:
What if a user searches for a travel in next year? With your model you'll have to create entries for all possible dates in the future, that's nearly unusable.

Think also about separating times and dates in different models, as they usually should be kept together, cause a ride from A to B at date x and time y is **one** object.

It might help to have a look at [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler), they solved some troubles with the use of Events and Occurences. Have a look at their pretty good docs.